# when I'm trying to use separate *.h and *.cpp I'm geting error LINK2019

Tags: visual-c++

I've code like

```
A.h
Class A{
  public:
    void FuncA();
}

A.cpp
#include "A.h"
void A::FuncA() {}

B.h
#include "A.h"

Class B{
  public:
    void FuncB();
}

B.cpp
#include "B.h"
void B::FuncB(){
  A *a = new A();
  a->FuncA();
}
```

When I'm trying to build this project I'm geting "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall A::FuncA()" (?FuncA@A@@QAEXH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall B::FuncB(void)" (?FuncB@B@@MAEXXZ) B.obj   project"

It makes A.obj and B.obj.

Comment: You are missing semicolons after the closing braces of your class declarations.  I don't think that's the problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks ok. Make sure to rebuild everything first and that A.obj is really sent to the linker.

---

Response to comment

Check the build log in VS2008. See picture below:

[image]

Comment: how can I make sure that A.obj is sent? I'm using VS2008

Comment: hmm, that's strange, I've made new project, added those files and it works fine now. Thank you.